# Fast image analysis

Tags: picamera

Attempting to measure objects with picamera at 10 frames per second by counting all the orange pixels. Using RPi 3, picamera V2, and OpenCV to measure pixel values in a 640x480 px image. My strategy was to go through pixel by pixel; if the pixel is within the BGR boundary for orange I would count it. I found that it takes more than 2 seconds to measure all 307,200 pixels - if I want 10 fps I can only measure ~300 pixels max. Is there any way to speed this up or have I hit a limit?
Python/pseudocode below:

```
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            k = result[i,j]
            if k==orange: count+=1
```

Comment: Python is effectively interpreted so you may do better in C.  One thing that sticks out in your code is that you assign k as the value then check k - why not `if result[i,j] = orange`

Comment: you can count in parallel, say using python multiprocessing. With 4 cores, perhaps you can count twice faster.

Comment: and you can "compile" you python code to make it a bit faster.